# Windows用SDKのmakeでエラーが出る

Tags: spresense, msys2

MSYS2をインストールして、次のステップで

```
$ tools/config.py --kernel release
```

を実行したところ、

```
make[1]: *** [Makefile.unix:300: include/arch] エラー１
make: *** [Makefile:308: olddefconfingkernel] エラー２
Post process failed. 512
Try 'make distcleankernel' first.
```

とエラーになってしまいます。

```
$ make distcleankernel
```

を実行しても、

```
/home/*****/spresense/nuttx/configs から出ます
include/arch/board already exits but is not a symbolic Link
make[1]: *** [Makefile.unix:357: clean_context] エラー１
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/*****/spresense/nuttx' から出ます
make: *** [Makefile:262: distcleankernel] エラー２
```

これらのエラーにどのように対処したらいいでしょうか。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。サポート外のWindows 7でした。Windows 10で再挑戦します。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

お問い合わせのWindowsでの開発環境について、記載いただいたログを確認したところ
MSYSを使用していないことが原因として考えられます。

MSYSをインストールした際、 `MSYS2 MSYS` の他に `MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit`, `MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit` がインストールされ、後者を利用するとこのような問題が発生します。

もしこのような状態になってしまった場合は、下記手順で問題解消することができます。

1. `MSYS2 MSYS` を起動します
2. 下記コマンドで開発環境をセットアップします

```
$ source ~/spresenseenv/setup
```

3. 下記コマンドで不要ファイルの削除を行います

```
$ cd "Spresense SDKのトップディレクトリ"
$ rm -rf nuttx/include/arch
$ rm -rf nuttx/arch/arm/src/board
```

こちらの手順で問題が解消できれば幸いです。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: $cd　でhomeに戻ってしまい、次の2行が有効に動作しませんでした。\spresense　に移動してから残り2行を実行することで該当２ファイルが削除され、無事復帰しました。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございました。お試しいただいた通り、"spresense"　ディレクトリ
（Spresense SDK のホームディレクトリ）に移動する必要があります。回答もそれに合わせて修正いたしました。この度はご確認にお手間をおかけし、誠に申し訳ありませんでした。引き続きSPRESENSEを、どうぞおよろしくお願いいたします。